# How to use .include? to capture multiple options resulting in same operation

Tags: ruby

I am writing a simple calculator that asks the user what calculation she wants to perform with a choice between '+', '-', '*' and '/'.

The code works when I separate each option with ||. However, I would prefer to use .include? to avoid repetition.

```
while play_again != "N"
  puts "Enter a first number:"
  first_num = gets.chomp.to_i
  puts "Enter a second number:"
  second_num = gets.chomp.to_i
  puts "Which operation would you like to perform? '+', '-', 'x', '/'"
  operator = gets.chomp
  if operator == "+" || operator == "-" || operator == "x" || operator   
  == "/"
    puts calculator(first_num, second_num, operator)
  else
    puts "That wasn't a valid selection."
  end
  puts "Do you want to calculate something else? (Y/N)"
  play_again = gets.chomp
end
```

I tried to rewrite the line starting with `if operator` with `if operator.include?(%w[+ - X /].to_s)` but this doesn't capture the user input properly and always puts " That wasn't a valid selection."

Comment: Here's a question for you: does the string `'+'` contain the array `['+', '-', 'X', '/']`?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I see my error now :) thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this way

```
if %w(+ - * /).include?(operator)
```

a shorter way for this one

```
if ["+", "-", "*", "/"].include?(operator)
```

This makes sense, don't you think? You're checking that the operator is included in some options. In this case the options are four strings, the symbols for the four basic mathematical operations.

Comment: Two variants: `"-+*/".include? operator` and `operator.match? /[-+*\/]/` (or `operator.match? /\+|-|\*|\//`).

Comment: @Ursus thank you for the answer! Makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 1):

A `case when` control structure lets you specify multiple conditionals. Sounds hard, is actually easy:

```
puts case operator
  when  '+', '-', 'x', '/' then calculator(first_num, second_num, operator)
  else "That wasn't a valid selection."
end
```